# Way to open up a list of Lead IDs

Tags: id, dataloader.io

I get a list of IDs back from Dataloader.io
[image]

I just want to open all of them. Is there a script/webapp where I can just paste a list of IDs and it would open then all up in new pages?

Answer (score 3):

You could log in to salesforce, copy and paste the ID values into your browser's console, surrounded by braces, and then use forEach:

```
['00Q000000000000','00Q000000000001','00Q000000000002'].forEach(function(v) { window.open('/'+v); });
```

To get a list that looks like that, I'd open the file in my favorite multi-purpose text editor, add a quote character before and after each line, add a comma between each, then stick on the brackets on either side. Of course, this is overkill, but you could do with with a bit of persistence.

Comment: there is also a cute trick to do the rows to delimited list of strings in Excel - http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution. Not perfect but perhaps doable.

I assume you are in a CSV/Excel. If so, create a new column and create a hyperlink formula.

If you make your formula: `http://<yourSfInstance>/<columnwithid>` (so it would look something like http://naxx.salesforce.com/00Q000000000LibD) then you can click each link and open it.

Not the most elegant, but better than 1000 copy-pastes.

Comment: Or, one could get *crazy* and just write up a Visualforce page to do it. It'd take like two minutes.